# DLLImport C# DLLNotFountExeption

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Перенесла проект с компьютера на ноут, после чего возникла проблема при запуске проекта.

Visual studio 2017

Пытаюсь из враппера на с# вызвать библиотеку на с++ и получаю ошибку "System.DllNotFoundException: "Не удается загрузить DLL "GRD_MBA.dll": Не найден указанный модуль. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8007007E)" "

с++ библиотека лежит в том же каталоге, что и exe враппера.
Так же попробовала скопировать эту с++ билиотеку в папку system32, но все равно получаю такую же ошибку. Почему среда не видит dll?

Код с c# проекта такой:

```
[DllImport("GRD_MBA.dll")]
private static extern unsafe void init(void** ppGrdMba);
```

так вызываю сам метод:

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (void* ppGrdMba = &_pGrdMba)
    {
        init((void**) ppGrdMba);
    }
}
```

Помогите.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А зависимости у этой библиотеки есть?

Comment: @VTT, библиотека не зависит от других проектов, но от нее зависит враппер.

Comment: Установлен ? `Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x64)`

Comment: @DigitalCore, да

Comment: @Naf точно зависимостей нет ? а в `using` видно библиотеку ?

Comment: @DigitalCore, точно нет. Вот во враппер я могу добавить эту библиотеку через usung только с ключевым словом static.

Comment: @DigitalCore, вообще эта с++ библиотека вызывает другие с++ dll и lib. Но ведь, если там была бы проблема, то я уже при компиляции увидела бы какую-то ошибку. Компиляция проходит без ошибок. Ошибку получаю во враппере при попытке вызвать метод из c++ библиотеки.

Comment: *"та с++ библиотека вызывает другие с++ dll"* а говорите зависимостей нет... dll при сборке вообще не используются и проблемы с их отсутствием на этом этапе не всплывают.

Comment: @VTT, ёпрст... да, действительно в этом была проблема.

Comment: @VTT: Напишете ответ?